# I'm trying to run console input in a thread in Java but my program is getting hungup on the readLine() method

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader, system.in

I'm creating this program to test getting user input in a thread for a chat server program. This program stops on `read = into.readLine();`. Why is that and what's happening?

Here is the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;

    public class ThreadClass implements Runnable
    {
        DataInputStream in;
        private boolean checkLoop = false;


    public void run()
    {
        BufferedReader into = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String read;
        System.out.println("Welcome...");
        while(!checkLoop)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("running1");
                read = into.readLine();
                System.out.println(read);
                if(read.equals(".bye"))
                {
                    checkLoop = true;
                }
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);System.out.println("running2");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                System.out.println(ie);System.out.println("running3");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("running4");
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        ThreadClass main = new ThreadClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(main);
        t1.start();
    }

    }
```

Comment: modify if condition : if(read.equals(".bye")) to if(read.equals("bye"))               why .bye while comparing??

Comment: @user403348255 that wont fix the problem with readLine()... Likely a typo.

Comment: Did you type something in the console?

Comment: Are you entering anything for the readLine to read? It needs data to read....

Comment: The console is not letting me enter anything into it. If I run this program apart w/o threading it then it works fine.

Comment: @user403348255   i do that in the event that the user isn't entering the word bye. This is code I pulled from my chat server program.

Comment: The program here runs correctly IMO, when I enter some data  - it prints it on screen and waits for my next input. The only issue is : if I type in "bye", the program won't exit. Hence, I pointed it out. @BenKnoble

Comment: Ok, so maybe its a problem with the Ide im using. I use BlueJ and im using a macbook pro.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i ran the program from terminal and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "read = into.readLine();" the program will stop and wait for the user to press the "Enter" key. Your program is working fine from my point of view.

Try to type something in console and you will see the program running correctly.